# Storing arrays in DynamoDB with AppSync with Resolver Mapping Template (edited)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm having some trouble storing arrays in DynamoDB on PutItem with AppSync, and it's turning me crazy :P

The problem is that the array I pass from GraphQl disappears when I run `$util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson`. What am I doing wrong?

I'm really stuck on this, and would very much appreciate any help I can get!

This is the template:

```
  #set($failing_list = [ "foo", 123, { "bar" : "baz" } ])

  {
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key": {
      "userId": { "S": "$ctx.args.input.email" },
      "createdAt": { "N": "$util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds()" }
    },
    "data" : {
      "test": $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson({
        "working_list": [ "foo", 123, { "bar" : "baz" } ],
        "failing_list": $failing_list
      })
    }
  }
```

This is the result:

```
  {
    version: '2017-02-28',
    operation: 'PutItem',
    key: {
      userId: { S: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' },
      createdAt: { N: '1531521284789' }
    },
    data: {
      test: {
        working_list: {
          L: [ { S: 'foo' }, { N: '123' }, { M: { bar: { S: 'baz' } } } ]
        },
        failing_list: {
          M: { L: { L: [ { M: { map: { M: {} } } }, { M: { map: { M: {} } } }, { M: { map: { M: {} } } } ] } }
        }
      }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$util.dynamodb.toListJson()` from the list of additional [DynamoDB helpers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html)?

Comment: That does not work either. I've changed the question to narrow it down. As you can see, it works when I put the array directly in to the json, but it fails if I refer to it...

Comment: However, everything works fine with the hack `$util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($util.parseJson($util.toJson($ctx.args.input)))`, which annoys me, because it's not pretty.